# Understanding with this Wordpress code

Tags: menus

I'm new to wordpress and tried to Google and looked up codex but it didn't help.
I downloaded a free theme from Github and I'm trying to learn how to make a theme by looking at its code. In the header.php I found this piece

```
<nav class="mainnav" role="navigation">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Menu', 'container' => 'false' )); ?>
  </nav>
```

I couldn't get this part " `array('menu' => 'Main Menu', 'container' => 'false' ));`"
Also I couldn't find the navigation markup anywhere in the theme.

Comment: Could you tell us, what exactly you didn't understand? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

`Displays a navigation menu created in the Appearance → Menus panel.`

Comment: I have the theme in HTML and I want to convert its navigation in Wordpress. Where do I define the elements of the navigation ? Also what if 'container' => true ?

Comment: From codex: `$container 
 (string) (optional) Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with. Allowed tags are div and nav. Use false for no container e.g. container => false 
 Default: div`

Comment: Thanks @Sn0opy, but where do I define the markup of different elements ?

Comment: Does this help anyway? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/customized-wp_nav_menu Otherwise I can't help you that much. Long time ago I worked with Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_nav_menu()` is a [template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) - that is function designed to be called in theme template file to output something.

This specific function generates and displays output of [navigation menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).

Arguments, you are asking about, determine that menu displayed should be looked up by "Main Menu" name and output should not be wrapped in `div` container, used by default. There are plenty more possible arguments, see [its documentation in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Internally this function also uses Walker-based class to generate output, but that gets into advanced stuff and may or may not be relevant to want you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The **'container' => 'false'** code indicates that the menu will not be surrounded by a  class. Try setting it to **'true'** and see what name the  gets. It should be:

```
<div class="menu">
```

or

```
<div class="navigation">
```

Feel free to style them using your *style.css* file.